# Did I miss something in the movie The Silence?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-silence

I ended up watching [The Silence](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7315484/) on a trip in an airplane.   So not sure if I missed something or if my son sitting next to me - not even watching - figured out a huge huge plot issue...

So these dinosaur birds attack everything that makes noise...   Why wouldn't people just build a cage and kill them by the thousands sitting behind bars and rebar with machine guns (and the guns would attract more)?   It would seem like this predator would be easy to combat since they were too aggressive.   Did I miss something that said this wouldn't work?   Or did a 9 year old break the plot of a multimillion dollar production?

Since this hasn't received any answers I will summarize a point from the comments.   These are super dumb birds/dinosaurs/whatever... Yes there are millions of them.   But... if I am in a military base and I start shooting them then supposedly any of them that can hear will attack.   Meaning one bunker and machine gun would wipe out the area.   Remember these birds had a hard time getting in a regular car.   So to mobilize you could have heavy armored trucks or tanks just roam and wipe out.   People would die from the birds at first but then the deaths should be more along the lines of starvation if there is a long-term issue in an area.   Nothing in the movie makes sense because they are simply too aggressive not to wipe out.

Comment: How would you build such cage without making noise?

Comment: @luciano - you could start your cage in a prison and move it... thousands of ways.   They couldn't get into a car so any rebar would work.   The making of the rebar cage is not the issue.

Comment: Right... this movie follows _these people_, maybe _other people_ did build it somewhere else? But this movie is not about that. _These characters_ were just regular folks that didn't have access to a prison or a machine gun. Plus... infinite bullets? How many birds were there?

Comment: @Luciano - that explanation isn't plausible to me.   There were references on TV and other sources through out the movie that EVERYONE is dying and at the end of the movie there are just a small percentage of the population that are living in nordic regions (where the birds don't like to go).   More plausible is the army makes a couple cages and shoots and shoots and shoots and these birds keep attacking until extinct.

Comment: it's a weak plot full of tv tropes: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/TheSilence2019

Comment: The heart of the question isn't the tropes it is the fact that these animals seem so dumb and easy to kill yet no one until the end of the movie in the nordics figured it out.   I mean there are thousands and thousands of places humans could go these things couldn't get in (pretty much any basement) and they seemed to be killed easily, yet all broadcasts during movie acted like they were impossible to kill or hide from.   I was very confused through out the whole movie, the car scene pushed everything over the top.

Comment: The military and most of the population were wiped out. Who was supposed to build a cage with miniguns? Stanley Tucci?

Comment: @Tk-421 - build a cage is just find a few pieces of rebar.   You could cut and work on the cage/rebar in any well made building (prison would be optimal).   That is the whole premise of the question - the population would not be wiped out by these, they would simply be a pest to those who were too dumb not to follow orders until they were cleared from their area.   They are simply too dumb and easy to kill.

Comment: @blankip - exactly - find a few pieces of rebar. Where? Get a welding machine - where? Get the guns - where?

Comment: @TK-421 - everyone is dead or gone.   You think you will have issues finding some metal and finding guns.   I mean you could just go to any gunshop and you will get both.   Let's not even make this hard.   How the hell did these dumb creatures wipe out any army base that has weapons, protection, and safe shelter?   My question was about the family (why wouldn't they live in a concrete building and make all the noise they want?) but nothing makes sense.  At least the silent place the bad guys were formidable not dumb easily killed birds.

Comment: Humans were probably outnumbered